# Numpy griddata interpolation up to certain radius

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm using `griddata()` to interpolate my (irregular) 2-dimensional depth-measurements; `x,y,depth`. The method does a great job - but it interpolates over the entire grid where it can find to opposing points. I don't want that behaviour. I'd like to have an interpolation around the existing measurements, say with up to an extent of a certain radius.

Is it possible to tell numpy/scipy: don't interpolate if you're too far from an existing measurement? Resulting in a NODATA-value? ideal = `griddata(.., .., .., radius=5.0)`

**edit example:**
In the image below; black dots are the measurements. Shades of blue are the interpolated cells by numpy. The area marked in green is in fact part of the picture but is considered as NODATA by numpy (because there's no points in between). Now, the red areas, are interpolated, but I want to get rid of them. any ideas?
[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't actually have a grid in {x,y,depth}, but some sparsely or randomly located points in that space?

Comment: @v.chaplin yes, that is correct. It is a bathymetric dataset. It has 'ramdomly' distributed measurements, including canals, islands etc. I used griddata for interpolation to an image. But e.g. islands are interpolated as being water. Thats nt true, and I want to get rid of that.

Comment: You want the interpolation to only be based on points within the threshold distance, or is that just for assigning `nan`?

Comment: hm, sort of.. First: basically every cell without a point within a certain radius from that cell, can be assigned NODATA. But also, in case of the shores around the island, I only want to interpolate using the points on that side of the island.

Comment: How were the red lines generated?

Comment: Ha, that would be nice chaplin, but sorry; it's Paint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok cool. I don't think there is a built-in option for `griddata()` that does what you want, so you will need to write it yourself.

This comes down to calculating the distances between `N` input data points and `M` interpolation points. This is simple enough to do but if you have a lot of points it can be slow at *~O(M*N)*. But here's an example that calculates the distances to all`N` data points, for each interpolation point. If the number of data points withing the radius is at least `neighbors`, it keeps the value. Otherwise is writes the value of `NODATA`.

`neighbors` is  4 because `griddata()` will use biilinear interpolation which needs points bounding the interpolants in each dimension (2*2 = 4).

```
#invec - input points Nx2 numpy array
#mvec - interpolation points Mx2 numpy array

#just some random points for example
N=100
invec = 10*np.random.random([N,2])

M=50
mvec = 10*np.random.random([M,2])

# --- here you would put your griddata() call, returning interpolated_values
interpolated_values = np.zeros(M)
NODATA=np.nan

radius = 5.0
neighbors = 4

for m in range(M):
    data_in_radius = np.sqrt(np.sum( (invec - mvec[m])**2, axis=1)) <= radius

    if np.sum(data_in_radius) < neighbors :
        interpolated_values[m] = NODATA
```

**Edit:**
Ok re-read and noticed the input is really 2D. Example modified.

Just as an additional comment, this could be greatly accelerated if you first build a coarse mapping from each point `mvec[m]` to a subset of the relevant data points. 
The costliest step in the loop would change from

`np.sqrt(np.sum( (invec - mvec[m])**2, axis=1))`

to something like

`np.sqrt(np.sum( (invec[subset[m]] - mvec[m])**2, axis=1))`

There are plenty of ways to do this, for example using a Quadtree, hashing function, or 2D index. But whether this gives performance advantage depends on the application, how your data is structured, etc.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. It at least seems to work with the sampledata. I'm not sure how adapt this to my datasets (sorry, numpy-noob..). Say I load the unstructured measurements from a .csv(x,y,d) file with np.loadtxt (->invec). What would the interpolation-points array look like?

Comment: The interpolation points are the locations at which you need interpolated values. If you're building an image, then these would be the locations of each pixel vertex or pixel center. For example if you're X ranges from 30.0 to 50.0 in steps of 0.5, and Y ranges 10.0 to 20 in steps of 0.5, you can do

Comment: `X = np.arange(30.0, 50.5, 0.5)`, then `Y = np.arange(10.0, 20.0, 0.5)` then `mvec = np.array( np.meshgrid( X, Y, indexing='ij') ).T`. A little advanced I know, but all this does is build an array of size `[ len(X)*len(Y),  2]`